# view all column names of two tables in same schema and compare them

Tags: database, oracle

I would like to view colum names of two tables and compare them sothat I can find out which col name is founded in one table but missing on other table. I use following query to display all colum names on table integer_table:

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM all_tab_columns
  WHERE table_name='integer_table';
```

This works fine.
Question: how can I display column names on other table "text_table" in second column sothat I can compare ? I tried following but I get ORA-00933 error:

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM all_tab_columns
  WHERE table_name='integer_table'
  LEFT JOIN
  SELECT column_name
  FROM all_tab_columns
  WHERE table_name='text_table';
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH tc1 AS (SELECT column_name FROM all_table_columns WHERE table_name = 'integer_table'),
     tc2 AS (SELECT column_name FROM all_table_columns WHERE table_name = 'text_table')
SELECT COALESCE(tc1.column_name, tc2.column_name) column_name,
       CASE WHEN tc1.column_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END present_in_integer_table,
       CASE WHEN tc2.column_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END present_in_text_table
FROM   tc1
       FULL OUTER JOIN tc2 ON tc1.column_name = tc2.column_name;
```

This query uses a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to join both sets of data; this means we select all records from both tables, regardless of whether there's a match or not.

Once the data has been joined, you can tell whether they matched or not by checking if the join column is null on either side.

If they're both not null, then we know there's a match, and therefore the value exists in both data sets.

If one is null but the other is not null, then we know the value exists only in the data set where it's not null.

Finally, `COALESCE()` is used to pick the first non-null value (e.g. if the value doesn't exist in the first data set, use the value from the second data set).

Comment: You should add a note that you probably need to write the `table_name` in uppercase, unless Ronald really created them in lowercase. Also note that `all_table_columns` may contain tables from more than one owner, so filtering the `OWNER` should be considered.